# Как отправить запрос на сервер ASP.NET Core через C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, запрос, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

У меня есть контроллер

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<User> Post([FromBody] User user)
  {
    return user;
  }
}
```

Нужно отправить запрос из другого приложения C# на действие в контроллере со сложным объектом User и получить ответ. Как это сделать?

Приложение .NET Core, формат данных запроса и ответа JSON.

Comment: Приложение .NET Core? Какой формат данных обмена с сервером, JSON? Можете показать ответ от сервера на конкретный запрос? Например, если вы сделаете запрос через приложение Postman, он вам покажет, что ответил сервер. Пожалуйста, подполните вопрос.

Comment: @aepot, я делал запрос через fetch в javascript, чтобы узнать в чем проблема, но вышла ошибка 404 Not Found.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать POST запрос, а вы скорее всего делаете GET. Попробуйте через Postman, это проще, и пригодится вам для тестирования в будущем.

Comment: Я указал метод "POST" при отправке fetch-запроса с заголовками Content-Type: application/json и Accept: application/json. Кст, я понял, что сервер возвращает пустую строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как неизвестно, что за конкретный запрос отправляется, и что за конкретный ответ ожидается, приведу демонстрационный пример.

К примеру, вы отправляете такой запрос

```
{"Message":"Hello!"}
```

А сервер отвечает

```
{"Status":"OK","Message":"Hello world!"}
```

Тогда модели данных для запроса и ответа будут выглядеть так

```csharp
public class RequestMessageData
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseMessageData
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Суть реализации методов в отправке и получении простых текстовых строк

```csharp
// HttpClient создается 1 раз на все время работы приложения
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// POST
private static async Task<string> PostRequestAsync(string url, string json)
{
    using HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// GET
private static async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

А использовать это можно вот так, .NET Core 3.1 Консольное приложение

```csharp
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text;
```

```csharp
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    RequestMessageData requestMessage = new RequestMessageData
    {
        Message = "Hello!"
    };

    try
    {
        string jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestMessage);
        string jsonResponse = await PostRequestAsync("http://myapi.url/path/to/method", jsonRequest);
        ResponseMessageData responseMessage = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessageData>(jsonResponse);
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", responseMessage.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", responseMessage.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

А вывод в консоль, если все прошло хорошо, будет такой

```
Status: OK
Message: Hello World!
```

Comment: помогите, пожалуйста. но мне очень нужна помощь. я в этом новичок. мне нужен код серверной части под тот запрос что вы написали. не могли бы вы его предоставить?

Comment: @petroglif к сожалению я ничего не знаю про ASP.NET.